# Aggregation COUNT doesn't Return some value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a newbie for using PostgreSQL, I want to count customer based on the region where the discount average is more than 0.4.

my query is like this

```
select
    c.region,
    count(o.customer_id) as customer_count,
    avg(o.discount)
from
    superstore_order o
join
    superstore_customer c
on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by
    1
having avg(o.discount) > 0.4
```

but when I run the query, it doesn't return some value. I tried to erase the count aggreagate like this

```
select
    c.region,
    o.customer_id,
    avg(o.discount)
from
    superstore_order o
join
    superstore_customer c
on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by
    1,2
having avg(o.discount) > 0.4
```

It return the value that I need but doesn't have condition for the discount. I want to count the data based on the region and the discount condition. Can someone help me? I'm sorry for my bad english too.

Comment: do You get result without avg: `select
    c.region,
    count(o.customer_id) as customer_count,
    avg(o.discount)
from
    superstore_order o
join
    superstore_customer c
on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by
    c.region`

Comment: @num8er yes, I get the result. but when I tried to add some condition using having, it doesn't

Comment: Try subquery: `SELECT * FROM (select     c.region,     count(o.customer_id) as customer_count,     avg(o.discount) as avg_discount from     superstore_order o join     superstore_customer c on o.customer_id = c.customer_id group by     c.region) region_customers WHERE region_customers.avg_discount > 0.4`

Comment: @num8er it doesn't show any result :(

Comment: then You don’t have that result where average is greater than 0.4, to check that try avg_discount >= 0

Comment: @num8er I was thinking like you too before. but actually, this case is from my online class. It's a multiple-choice question, all the choices have a value :(. I've tried using >= 0 it works

Comment: please check without where avg_discount, to see what avg You have

Comment: @num8er it's 0.1 .... not greater than 0.4. But when I tried the second query from my question, it has several data that > 0.4

Comment: @num8er and if no result, there's no answer that interpretation that result

Comment: but afaik when You do group by region it isn’t. Try to check it Yourself, take one region and summarize discounts and divide by count of records

Comment: @num8er i have edited my second query in my question. It show the result what I need (discount > 0.4) but how can I count total cust because when I used the count like first query, it doesn't show?

Comment: count(o.customer_id) does not count customers, it counts number of rows where customer_id exists (not null); try count(distinct o.customer_id)

Comment: @tinazmu it has no result too :(

Comment: What you are describing tells us that, in your data, you don't have a region where the average of o.discount over all rows for the region is over 0.4. If you believe this is not the case, can you choose the region that you believe must have average over 0.4, then give us the results of `select count(*), sum(o.discount) from
    superstore_order o join superstore_customer c on o.customer_id = c.customer_id where c.region=theregionyoubelievemusthaveit`.

Comment: better to provide table structure with data. return value of avg(discount) doesn't match with 0.4 I guess.